# C - split string

Tags: c, string, char, scanf

How can I process this string if I want to make it 4 words. If I use sscanf it will split the word 'Face masks' into two. Or can sscanf be used somehow to prevent this from happening?

input:

```
2021-01-01 2021-7-1 'Face masks' "Wear everywhere"
2000-08-05 2010-8-8 LOCKDOWN 'xxxxx'
```

output:

```
2021-01-01
2021-7-1 
'Face masks' 
"Wear everywhere"
....
```

Comment: You can use `%[^'\"]` to match a string not containing quotes.

Comment: But that won't work if the quotes are optional. `scanf()` is not a general purpose parser. It sounds like you need to write code to recognize all the different possible formats.

Comment: You could first replace quotes with spaces if you are allowed to modify the string.

Comment: @Devolus: if you do that, you can no longer tell where the 3rd word ends and and the 4th word starts :)

Comment: Ah, I missunderstood the posting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`scanf()` is not powerful enough for your purpose, because of optional quotes and possibly empty words (`''` or `""`).

Here is a generic hand coded parser:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// split a string into up to count words stored in a 2D array of char
int split(char output[][100], int count, const char *str) {
    // recognises space separated words and quoted content without
    // embedded quotes of the same type. Quotes are stripped in output.
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        const char *start;
        int len;

        str += strspn(str, " \t\f\v\r\n");
        if (*str == '\0')
            return i;
        if (*str == '\'') {
            start = ++str;
            len = strcspn(str, "\'");
            str += len;
            str += (*str == '\'');
        } else
        if (*str == '\"') {
            start = ++str;
            len = strcspn(str, "\"");
            str += len;
            str += (*str == '\"');
        } else {
            start = str;
            len = strcspn(str, " \t\f\v\r\n");
            str += len;
        }
        snprintf(output[i], sizeof(output[i]), "%.*s", len, start);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you this is what I tried to make for all the time :)

Comment: I'd use a switch like [this](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/37ac3W) to avoid code duplication

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili: factorizing the code is tempting, but removes the opportunity for the compiler to inline `strcspn()` for constant strings, which I have not seen them do yet but is possible and would be useful for single character strings.